# Read US-ASCII File in go

Tags: go

currently I try to read a us-ascii file into golang, but everytime I do so, every special sign, like Ä Ö Ü ß gets replaced with a ? or on my database with the special sign ?.

Is there anything I could do to prevent it?

Here is how I read my file:

```
file, err := os.Open(path)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
var lines []string
r := bufio.NewReader(file)
for {
    line, err := r.ReadBytes('\n')
    if err != nil {
        break
    }
    lines = append(lines, string(line))
}
fmt.Println(strings.Join(lines, ""))
index.Content = strings.Join(lines, "")
```

Comment: It's not ascii if it contains unicode characters

Comment: ```file file.txt 
file.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators``` It's a txt file created on windows

Comment: `file` can only guess the encoding by reading part of the file. UTF-8 shouldn't usually have a BOM, so if the non-ascii characters are far enough into the file it will never see them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the letters Ä Ö Ü ß  doesn't exist in US-ASCII, I would make an educated guess that you are actually dealing with the Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) encoding.

Converting from Latin-1 can be done like this:

```
runes := make([]rune, len(line))
for i, b := range line {
    runes[i] = rune(b)
}
lines = append(lines, string(runes))
```

**Edit:**

The example is not optimized, but it shows how a Latin-1 byte can be stored in a `rune` as the values of Latin-1 corresponds directly to the Unicode code point. The actual encoding into UTF-8 is then done when converting `[]rune` to `string`.

Comment: ty. and yes it seems that it is latin-1 under linux i get us-ascii when i check the file with file filename.txt.. damit windows.

Comment: @ChristianSchmitt ISO 8859-1 is an expansion of ASCII and Unicode is an expansion of ISO 8859-1. Beware about one tiny thing though: ISO 8859-1 maps ¤ to the codepoint where ISO 8859-15 maps the € sign. If you use the € sign in your data, you might want to manually perform replacements.